# TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'\\' at 205 Airflow Macros

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I am getting the following error :

```
File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'\\' at 205
```

When I include this in my code:

```
'{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -13), "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y%m%d") }}'
```

I re-typed it in vim in case it was an error with encoding, but still no luck!

Comment: Is `macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -13), "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y%m%d")` supposed to be a variable?

Comment: I've assigned it to a variable, yes

Comment: Usually, you put the variable in the `{{}}` and put code in the backend.

Comment: That'w what I've done above, i,e put variable_name = {{ macros blah blah }}

Comment: I don't think variables can have spaces

Comment: Well I pulled this from a code segment that works for someone else, so I don't see why it should fail. Also it's a string till the template it evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Change to this:

```py
"{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -13), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%m%d') }}"
```

Airflow jinja templates does not accept " in the middle of your template. I've had this same problem using this same ds_format macro. Always represents strings inside your template with ', for example: 'my_string', and it should work.